# Trying to MPI_Send and MPI_Recv char array getting garbage

Tags: mpi

I'm trying to create a log file from each processor and then send that to the root as a char array. I first send the length and then I send the data. The length sends fine, but the data is always garbage! Here is my code:

```
MPI_Barrier (MPI_COMM_WORLD);
string out = "";

MPI_Status status[2];
MPI_Request reqs[num_procs];

string log = "TEST";
int length = log.length();
char* temp = (char *) malloc(length+1);
strcpy(temp, log.c_str());

if (my_id != 0)
{
    MPI_Send (&length, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send (&temp, length+1, MPI_CHAR, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}   
else {      
    int length;
    for (int i = 1; i < num_procs; i++)
    {
        MPI_Recv (&length, 2, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status[0]);
        char* rec_buf;
        rec_buf = (char *) malloc(length+1);
        MPI_Recv (rec_buf, length+1, MPI_CHAR, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status[1]);
        out += rec_buf;
        free(rec_buf);
    }
}

MPI_Barrier (MPI_COMM_WORLD);
free(temp);
```

Comment: You can add an answer. You just have to wait a certain amount of time. If you go back and add your answer now, it won't show up as unanswered and you can mark it as answered by yourself (after another waiting period).

Comment: yes please add your answer below

Comment: Why are you sending one words with `MPI_Send (&length, 1, ...)` but receiving two words `MPI_Recv (&length, 2, ...)`?

Comment: Also, why all your message tags are 1? Quoting from [Message Passing Interface (MPI)](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/): "Send and receive operations should match message tags."

Answer (score 5):

You are passing a `char**` to `MPI_Send` instead of a `char*` this causes memory corruption, or in your case the garbled output you are getting. Everything should be fine if you use

```
MPI_Send (temp, length+1, MPI_CHAR, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

(note the removed `&` in front of the first argument, `temp`.)